# Acess data from Start Page using Ionic 2 + Angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

**EDIT**

I have a web service Rest which provides a menu like this:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "content-type": "one",
      "title": "title1",
      "url": "url1";
    },
    {
      "content-type": "two",
      "title": "title2",
      "url": "url2"
    }
  ]
}
```

In my start page I get this menu, and It gives dynamic content, which provides different pages.

```
@Component({
    providers: [APIClient],
    templateUrl: 'build/app.html',
    selector: 'my-app'
})
class MyApp {
    @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

    rootPage: any = SomeComponent;

    @Input() url: string;


    pages: Array<{ title: string, component: any, url: string }>;

    constructor(public platform: Platform, private _apiClient: APIClient) {

        this.initializeApp();
        this._apiClient.get("http://localhost:8080/MyApp/context/menu",
            'menu',
            null,
            (data) => this.handleSuccessGetMenu(data),
            null);
    }

    initializeApp() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
            // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        });
    }

    openPage(page) {
        // Reset the content nav to have just this page
        // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
        this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
    }



    handleSuccessGetMenu(data) {


        if ("" != data.items) {
            this.pages = [];
            for (var item of data.items) {

                if (item['content-type'] === "one" || item['content-type'] === "two") {
                    this.pages.push({ title: item['title'], component: DynamicComponent, , url: item['url'] });
                    this.url = item['url'];
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
ionicBootstrap(MyApp);
```

I want to access url on my component but I don´t know how to accomplish that.

```
@Component({
  providers: [APIClient],
  templateUrl: './build/components/dynamic.html'
})
export class DynamicComponent {

//HOW CAN I ACESS URL

private dynamicurl=myapp.url;

  //construtor
  constructor(private _apiClient: APIClient, public navParams: NavParams) {
         **IT´S POSSIBLE THIS WAY to GET URL FOR CURRENT PAGE?**
   console.log(navCtrl.get('url'));

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

App Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
            <child [url]="link"></child>`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  link: string = "hello";

  ngOnInit(): void {

  };

}
```

Child Component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template: `
      {{ url }}
    `
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() url;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      console.log(this.url);
    };
}
```

See my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/gRtCTX5PiULnGW6HDrVl) for an example on how you would access your url from parent component. I'm not sure if this applies to Ionic but if it's angular 2 it should be the same process.

I hope this is what you are looking for, based on my understanding of your question.